# RAILS - MASS MANDRILL

Tags: ruby-on-rails, bulk, mandrill

How to add separate email content(template content) for each user in mandrill. For example,for User A I need to send the content as "Question1" and for B the email content will be "Question B".Does anybody knows how to achieve this.I am using mass mandrill gem .This is a rails application

mail(to: [emailid["email"]],
                 from: current_user_email,
                 subject: subject,
                 template:"My-template",
                 template_content: template_content,
                 global_merge_vars: global_merge_vars,
                 merge_vars: merge_vars).deliver

Now I want send like this template_content1 for user A,template_content2 for User B.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think it is not possible to send several emails with different templates to different people in just one API request, doesn't seem like a `mass_mandrill` limitation to me, rather one imposed by Mandrill's API.

If your templates don't differ *that* much, maybe, you can instrument what you want by using `global_merge_vars` and `merge_vars`, but perhaps is easier to just make one API call for each different template you want to use.

If you are concerned about the performance impact you can always send emails on background or set the `async` option to `true`.